# How to implement initializer_list constructor for a wrapper of std::map

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

Here is a simple wrapper class for `std::map`. I want to be able to use an initializer list to construct objects of type `Wrapper` (see main function), however this implementation does not work.

```
#include <map>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Key {
    Key(int k) : key(k) {}
    int key;
};

struct Value{
    Value(int v) : value(v) {}
    int value;
};

class Wrapper {
    public:
        Wrapper(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, Value>> initList) 
            : m_map(initList) {}

    private:
        std::map<Key, Value> m_map;
};


int main() {
    Wrapper w = {{2, 2}, {1,1}};
}
```

The compiler gives me this error:

`error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::map<Key, Value>' : m_map(initList) {}`

It was my understanding that the template parameter for `std::intializer_list` is supposed to be what the container that is being initialized is storing internaly.
Since `std::map` stores key-value pairs as `std::pair<const key_type, value_type>` I thought this was correct
I also tried explicitly adding `const` in both m_map definition and in the constructor (like `std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, Value>>` but I am still getting compile errors

Comment: `std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, Value>>` is correct. The other error is due to missing `<` for the key.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added an ```operator<``` to ```Key``` class like so:    ```bool operator<(const Key& other) { return key < other.key; }```, and also added ```const``` where you suggested and still getting compile error

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/vM6zjP1M4) after fixing issues mentioned by HolyBlackCat.

Comment: What that structs should be good for? Use typedefs instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that *Key* should be `const` in the `initializer_list`:

```cpp
Wrapper(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, Value>> initList)
```

A `std::map` also needs the *Key* s to be comparable using `operator<`. You can add it as a free function:

```cpp
bool operator<(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) {
    return lhs.key < rhs.key;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v4bP8x6T1)

or as a member function

```cpp
struct Key {
    Key(int k) : key(k) {}

    bool operator<(const Key& rhs) const {
//                                 ^^^^^   <- note that it should be const
        return key < rhs.key;
    }

    int key;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/111qTj18r) - The member function needs to be `const` because the `map` couldn't call a non-`const` qualified member function on a *Key* since the *Key* s are not allowed to change once inserted into the `map`.

Comment: I'd reverse the stuff below "also note" and the stuff above; the OP's described error is the lack of `const Key` fundamentally.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Good idea. Updated.